# Do we need to specify "protocol" when "type" is SOCK_DGRAM or SOCK_STREAM in socket()?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, udp

From APUE

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

Where:

- `type` can be `SOCK_DGRAM, SOCK_RAW, SOCK_SEQPACKET, SOCK_STREAM`, and
- `protocol` can be `IPPROTO_TCP`, `IPPROTO_UDP`, ...

Can `SOCK_DGRAM`  work with `IPPROTO_UDP`, but not with `IPPROTO_TCP`?

Can `SOCK_STREAM`  work with `IPPROTO_TCP`, but not with `IPPROTO_UDP`?

If answers are yes, does it mean that we don't need to specify `protocol` when `type` is `SOCK_DGRAM` or `SOCK_STREAM` ?

Answer (score 3):

From the man page for `socket(2)`:

> The  *protocol*  specifies  a  particular  protocol  to  be used with
>   the
>          socket.  Normally only a single protocol exists to support a particular
>          socket  type within a given protocol family, in which case protocol can
>          be specified as 0.  However, it is possible  that  many  protocols  may
>          exist,  in  which  case a particular protocol must be specified in this
>          manner.  The protocol number to use is specific to  the  “communication
>          domain” in which communication is to take place; see protocols(5).  See
>          getprotoent(3) on how to map protocol name strings to protocol numbers.

So whether the **protocol** field needs to be specified or not depends both on the **domain** and **type** field.  Assuming domain is `AF_INET`, i.e. IPv4, then the protocol field should be set to 0 for both `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_STREAM`.  The man page for `ip(7)` shows this:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/socket.h>
>    #include <netinet/in.h>
>    #include <netinet/ip.h> /* superset of previous */
>
>    tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
>    udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
>    raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, protocol);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> An   IP  socket  is  created  by  calling  the  socket(2)  function
>   as    socket(AF_INET,  socket_type,  protocol).   Valid  socket 
>   types   are    SOCK_STREAM  to  open  a  tcp(7)  socket,  SOCK_DGRAM 
>   to open a udp(7)    socket, or SOCK_RAW to open a raw(7) socket to
>   access the  IP  protocol    directly.   protocol is the IP protocol in
>   the IP header to be received    or sent.  **The only valid values for
>   protocol are 0 and IPPROTO_TCP  for    TCP  sockets,  and 0 and
>   IPPROTO_UDP for UDP sockets.**  For SOCK_RAW you    may specify a valid
>   IANA IP protocol defined in RFC 1700 assigned  numbers.

The `ipv6(7)` man page shows something different:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/socket.h>
>    #include <netinet/in.h>
>
>    tcp6_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
>    raw6_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, protocol);
>    udp6_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, protocol);
> ```

It seems that for IPv6 you can specify the `protocol` field, although the man page doesn't say anything regarding what values are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51996880/10871073) is outdated. Here's what current [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) for `ip(7)` states:

> ```
> protocol is the IP protocol in the IP header to be received or sent.
> Valid values for protocol include:
>
>
>    •  0 and IPPROTO_TCP for tcp(7) stream sockets;
>
>    •  0 and IPPROTO_UDP for udp(7) datagram sockets;
>
>    •  IPPROTO_SCTP for sctp(7) stream sockets; and
>
>    •  IPPROTO_UDPLITE for udplite(7) datagram sockets.
>
>    For SOCK_RAW you may specify a valid IANA IP protocol defined in
>    RFC 1700 assigned numbers.
> ```

As you can see, currently there are two different protocols for each of the stream and datagram socket types. And the `protocol` parameter is what specifies which one of them to use for the corresponding socket type.